# Powershell unable to add value to Excel cell

Tags: excel, powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a Powershell script which inserts values into multiple rows, columns and sheets of an Excel file.

The script works fine, except for 1 column. The cells within the problem column are "select" cells, they have a small set of values to select from "update", "create" and "delete". When the script runs no errors are reported, the cells simply remain empty.

This is the code to insert the values:

```
$Worksheet.Cells.Item($Row, 8).Value2 = $Obj.Value
```

There are several other "select" cells within the sheets and all the others work fine, just column "8" within the 1 sheet is a problem. I've reviewed the `$Obj.Value` and the values match (from what I can tell).

Is there another way to set the cell value? What I've tried so far:

```
$Worksheet.Cells.Item($Row, 8) = $Obj.Value  # Same result as .Value2

$Worksheet.Cells.Item($Row, 8).Text = $Obj.Value # Throws an Exception: "Unable to set the Text property of the Range class"
```

Is there another way to set the value? Is there something I need to check within the Excel file?

Also, when I open the file in Excel, I can manually edit the cell with no noticable issues - I am currently lost as to why the script can't maintain the cells.

**Solution**

Interferring VBA code.

Comment: Would you be able to install the excel module?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala, which Excel module? I have Excel installed on my machine and as I mentioned, other than 1 column/cell the script works fine.

Comment: Can you double-check that `$Obj.Value` has an actual value when the command runs? Excel's validation doesn't do anything when inserting values this way. I also recommend the `ImportExcel` module (but more for handling tables and other more complicated excel objects).

Comment: [This Module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/7.1.0).

Comment: There's always `$Obj.Value | Clip; $Worksheet.Cells.Item($Row, 8).Paste()` to copy/paste the value in as an alternative.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician that's an interesting approach, but it didn't work for me. The following Exception is thrown: "Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] does not contain a method named 'Paste'." Which is kind of good, as now I know it's not a normal Cell, right!?

Comment: It may consider what you have to be a `range` instead of a `cell` (admittedly, a range of 1 cell). In which case you should be able to use `.PasteSpecial()` instead of `.Paste()`

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the cause of the issue, there was a hidden VBA function which reacted on an update to the column, which seemed not to affect user input, however it is what was stopping the script from working.

After modifying the VBA code, the script works fine again.

Thanks everyone for your comments/feedback.